# Pre-downloaded base image on azure windows vm

Tags: azure, containers, virtual-machine, server-core

Does Azure virtual machine "windows 2019 datacenter with containers" always have the servercore base image pre-downloaded?

I created a few of this type of VM today, all of them got servercore, windows, and nanoserver images pre-downloaded (created 2 weeks ago). But on the vm I created one month ago, the base image was only downloaded when my dockerfile asked for it, during "docker run".

Answer (score 0):

With the test, I think these three Windows docker images are built-in in the VM image 2019-datacenter-with-Containers. You can see the screenshot here:

[image]

The images stored in driver C when the VM is created. You know drive C is almost the VM image if you only create the VM without any actions. I'm not one hundred percent sure, but probably, it's the truth.